# No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp_ejr26m6.upload.mp3' in Django

Tags: python, django, file

I recently adjusted the location of media files when I was presented with this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp1d93dhp7.upload.mp4'` in Django. So far I've checked for typos in my file location code in my settings, views and models.

The website works by simply storing user uploaded media files in a media folder.

Here is the relevant code:

views.py:

```
...
if form.is_valid() and 'file' in request.FILES:
                if not request.session.get('user_id'):
                    request.session['user_id'] = generate_unique_id()
                user_id = request.session.get('user_id')
                uploaded_file = request.FILES.getlist('file')

                
                for file in uploaded_file:
                    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # Use MEDIA_ROOT for permanent storage
                    filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
                    uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
                    file_type = mimetypes.guess_type(uploaded_file_path)

                    request.session['uploaded_file_path'] = uploaded_file_path
                
                
                    #user_doc, created = RequirementsChat.objects.get_or_create(id=user_id)
                
                    user_doc, created = RequirementsChat.objects.get_or_create(id=user_id)
                    uploaded_file = UploadedFile(input_file=file, requirements_chat=user_doc, chat_id = user_id)
                    uploaded_file.save()
                    user_doc.save()
                #save details
                    user_doc, created = RequirementsChat.objects.get_or_create(id = user_id)
                    user_doc.alias = alias
                    user_doc.email = email
                    user_doc.language = language
                    user_doc.due_date = due_date
                    user_doc.subtitle_type = subtitle_type
                    user_doc.transcript_file_type = transcript_file_type
                    user_doc.additional_requirements = additional_requirements
                    user_doc.date = timezone.now()
                    user_doc.save()
                    return HttpResponse(status=200)
...
```

The error seems to be caused by the `uploaded_file.save()` line( I used print statements to confirm. Nothing is printed to the console after this line).

models.py:

```
class RequirementsChat(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    transcript_file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    additional_requirements = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    task_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='human_upload/')#new
    chat_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, null= True)
    requirements_chat = models.ForeignKey(RequirementsChat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_files', null=True)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),#redirects to transcribe/,
    path('transcribe/', include('transcribe.urls')),
    path('human/', include('human.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(
settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

My media folder structure is `mysite > media> human_upload`

Comment: In your UploadedFile class, you have specified upload_to='human_upload/'. However, in your media folder structure, you mentioned it's human_uploads.

Comment: @jepozdemir Hi. That was a typo. It's `human_upload`. I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Problem :-

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='human_upload/')#new
```

And

```
My media folder structure is mysite > media> human_uploads
```

Look at upload path. It's different in above two.

**Answer :-**

Make them same path.

---

Thanks to @jepozdemir's comment.

Comment: Hi. That was a typo. It's human_upload. I corrected.

Comment: Does it work after correction?

Comment: Where does the `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp1d93dhp7.upload.mp4' ` generate from?